# How do I make custom blocks show up only in creative mode

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-addons

I am trying to create a tardis/doctor who map, my idea is to make a bunch of custom blocks each the same colour with different opacity so I could use commands to make them fade, so I could make the tardis look like it was fading in and out

What I want to know is if I create a custom block is there anyway to keep that block hidden if the player is in survival mode? This is for bedrock edition, on android

Comment: not give the player the item?

Comment: That's not the point, the point is so that the player can be in survival mode and not be able to see the blocks in the crafting guide, since I'm thinking of reusing the code for other blocks to make the new blocks

Comment: so like, an uncraftable block? pretty sure quite a few of those exist

Answer (score 1):

You can just not add a crafting recipe, and bam it's unobtainable. You can even set one of the components, `"minecraft:loot": "loot_tables/empty"` to make it drop nothing if placed down.

Unfortunately without, doing some command work, what you are asking for specifically is not directly possible.